# UIWebView autorotation bug?

Tags: uiwebview

Please, any help in my problem:

I have UIWebView as subview at viewController.view, and it has autoresizing set properly to fit screen bounds in any orientation. The problem is:

Rotation works properly, but if I do zoom out, and then rotate, UIWebView frame sets right, but its content is still in landscape. Seems to its UIWebView bug, but maybe someone know the solution.

P.S.
webView.scalesPagesToFit = YES;
Without any pinch (to zoom out), works great.
I've attached video link, to make the problem more clear (autoresizing mask is visible in IB).
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11819370/Bugs/RotationBug.mov

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these:

```
[self.view setNeedDisplay];
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
```

Comment: Nope, the problem is still here:(

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things. I have had this problem when switching from Landscape to Portrait mode, where the UIWebView keeps the same size. I wasn't able to view your video as the dropbox link no longer worked. But there are two things you can try. First is to just try setting the viewport as follows in the `<head>` tag in the html page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

If that doesn't work, I added in a native call to execute javascript which sets the viewport correctly. You can see the code at the other [other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007904/uiwebview-donest-resize-correctly-when-orientation-change/6104537#6104537)  I answered.