# Resize/fit content ONLY HEIGHT of UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, scroll

I'm almost done with resizing my UIWebView. I used the delegate method :

**In .h :**

```
@interface myController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

**In .m :**

```
#pragma mark UIWebView delegate methods

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad : (UIWebView *) aWebView
{
    CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    aWebView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    aWebView.frame = frame;
}
```

But what I need is a webview with fixed-width and variable-height depending on the content.
The previous code is almost fine but the webview is also extended and scrollable horizontally. 
I also tried this :

```
[myWebView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

But it only disables the scroll, not adapts the content.

How to fix this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help. I got it working quite easily:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6104537/1413088