# iOS App UIWebview is not showing my website responsive

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, webview

I have a responsive website which i tried adding in uiwebview. When testing in the simulator with iphone 5 it displays the website correctly, but when displaying on iphone 6 it leaves about 20px blank.

I have trief different solutions like here; [UIWebView dones't resize correctly when orientation change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007904/uiwebview-donest-resize-correctly-when-orientation-change/6104537#6104537)

But without result.

Is there anyone who can help me on the way?

Comment: Can you post some of your css?

Comment: @media (max-width: 782px) {
  .admin-bar #wrapper, .admin-bar #mobile-site-navigation {
    padding-top: 46px; }

  .admin-bar #header-wrapper.header-sticked {
    top: 46px; } }

I'm using A Wordpress website with a theme, I have tried different wordpress websites without result

Comment: Did you check webview's constraints? Can you share some screenshot link?

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant this but: http://imgur.com/JEVw7FU

Comment: @D13367 I meant the screenshot when you run the app on iphone 6

Comment: Oh okay, here is the screenshot: http://imgur.com/w1YWKcr

Comment: Looks like you would have to set the storyboard constraints on the view of the webview so that it takes the whole width of the screen.